# How to detect interframe codecs in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

In ffmpeg, is there any way to tell if a codec (`AVCodec` or `AVCodecContext`) supports interframe encoding?

Comment: See the feature request: https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/243.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility of interframe is not indicated in the AVCodec structure itself

Header file avcodec.h
http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/avcodec.h;h=fdc86bb7c09025df30ff7536a0dd9a55efabb20c;hb=HEAD#l628
defines no CODEC_CAP_* capability flag for interframe support

It is internal capability of codec, which may be indicated only as text in Profile description e.g. FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH_10_INTRA